# Error adding a new view page in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am quite new to MVC. I am trying to create a new view page (using a layout page option) but I keep getting the error;

```
There was an error running the selected code generator the document cannot be opened. It has been renamed, deleted or moved.
```

Please how do I resolve this?

[image: Here's a screenshot of the error]

Comment: delete the "Movie" folder also from Views, and then try to create the view.

Comment: The Movie folder is fine that is the views for the Movie controller. Which layout are you selecting?

Comment: "_Layout.cshtml" under the shared folder

Comment: Just create a new file under your folder `/Views/Movie` called `Random.cshtml`